# Step by step debug crash VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

i have a problem in my macro then i wanted to debug it using step by step (using F8) but when i enter in this, my step-by-step crashed and the macro finished (with bugs)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub create_fsm_Cliquer()

    Dim MaFeuille As Worksheet
    Dim nombre_de_vdd As Integer
    Dim nom_fichier_sauvegarde As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim nb_ligne As Integer
    Dim dernier_rev As String
    Dim word_fichier As Document
    Dim fichier As String
    Dim word_app As Word.Application
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim reponse As Object
    Dim footr As Object
     
    
    Set MaFeuille = Sheets("Info FSM")
    
    dernier_rev = MaFeuille.Cells(5, 2)

    nombre_de_vdd = MaFeuille.Cells(2, 2)

    nb_ligne = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , , xlPrevious).Row

    fichier = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "fsm_template_balises.docx"
    
    Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With word_app
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = 1
    End With
    
    Set word_fichier = word_app.Documents.Open(fichier)

    For i = 14 To nb_ligne
        For Each footr In word_fichier.Sections(1).Footers
            With footr.Range.Find
               .Text = MaFeuille.Cells(i, 1)
               .Replacement.Text = MaFeuille.Cells(i, 2)
               .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next footr
    Next i

    nom_fichier_sauvegarde = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "fsm_template_balises_" & dernier_rev & ".docx"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If (fs.FileExists(nom_fichier_sauvegarde)) Then
        reponse = fs.DeleteFile(nom_fichier_sauvegarde, True)
    End If
    word_fichier.SaveAs nom_fichier_sauvegarde

    word_fichier.Close
    word_app.Quit
    
End Sub
```

My macro crashed when the step-by-step reached the line
`.Replacement.Text = MaFeuille.Cells(16, 2)`

Edit : im using an excel macro to work on a .docx

Edit : the result is that my first footer is good, but the others are the same as before the execution

Comment: You do not show all your code, and this is not as it should... What `MaFeuille` is? A table in a document page? A sheet in Excel? How was it declared and `Set`?

Comment: Also, what exact error is returned?

Comment: @JvdV there is no error, my step by step debug freezes then the macro finishes with no error.

Comment: You did not show anything relevant after editing... Where `nb_ligne` received a value? Again, what `MaFeuille` is and how was it declared/set? How do you access `Word` session?

Comment: @FaneDuru, didnt thought it is usefull informations, i edited with my full code

Comment: But the Word way of doing what you try is correct. It is a matter of something not correctly supplied by the previous code. So, place a break point on the line `For i = 14 To nb_ligne` and run the code. When the code stops on that line, move the cursor over the involved variables from above (`nb_ligne`, `dernier_rev` etc.). Does it show what you expect from all of them?

Comment: Does your word document have several sections? I guess your code changes only the footer of the first section.

Comment: @FaneDuru, all my variables are good

Comment: I am afraid that this cannot be true... Try copying the problematic part (modifying the Footers content) in Word, adapt the values ("X" instead of `MaFeuille.Cells(i, 1)` and "Y" instead of `MaFeuille.Cells(i, 2)` and run the code. I am sure that it will work without any error...

Comment: @Shrotter, it's another problem lol, i dont know how to execute this code to all sections so i wanted to debug it then i got this problem. But if you have an idea to change all the sections, im in :)

Comment: @FaneDuru, already tried it, i have the same problem, the step by step  debugger freezes with the line ```.Replacement.Text = MaFeuille.Cells(i, 2)``` then the macro finish by itself, idk why

Comment: I am afraid that we speak different languages, no offence... **` MaFeuille.Cells(i, 2)` must not exist there**"... It should be "Y". This only may prove that one of the used objects does not exist in the initial code, too.

Comment: @FaneDuru, i misread your comment, my bad. It's working but i need to get my "X"'s from a tables in excel. all my variables come from excel sheets, i want to modify the Word doc with these tables.

Comment: Word does not care if the string to be replaced comes from an Excel sheet range or is written by you as "X". Please, check again the variables content after placing of the suggested Break point. The problem have to be found there. What you checked in Word directly, only proved that my supposition is right... Please, place `Option Explicit` on tot of the module keeping the code in Excel. Maybe there are typos in the code...

Comment: @FaneDuru, already have the Option Explicit on the top of my code. I figured it out that i dont have this problem anymore because i removed the Sections(2) of my Word, all of my document is based on an one section now. And MaFeuille.Cells(i,2) is existing (i tried now). I dont know why the step by step is crashing when i have 2 sections in my Word now :(

Comment: Theoretically, it should rise a relevant error telling about the section missing. But there still are bad behaviors from this point of view. That's why you should dig and see what bothers the code. But, I tested your code using `Section(1)`. Where from `Section(2) appeared? If you would show it, I probably would face a similar behavior and worn you. I  tested it and it worked without any problem...

Comment: @FaneDuru Section(2) dont appear in my code, but i have a second section that i didnt see in my Word, i think that was the problem. I agreed with you, i dont understand why i didnt get the section missing error, ill dig it. Thanks for your time